# "use of moved value" when matching while merging two vectors

Tags: rust, borrowing

I am writing a merge function for vectors of tags with counts, but am getting borrowing errors.

```
fn merge(mut l1: Vec<(String, u32)>, mut l2: Vec<(String, u32)>) -> Vec<(String, u32)> {
    let mut d1 = l1.drain(..);
    let mut d2 = l2.drain(..);
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut v1 = d1.next();
    let mut v2 = d2.next();
    loop {
        match (v1, v2) {
            (None, None) => return result,
            (None, Some(x)) => {
                result.push(x.clone());
                v2 = d2.next()
            }
            (Some(x), None) => {
                result.push(x.clone());
                v1 = d1.next()
            }
            (Some(p1), Some(p2)) => {
                let (ref s1, t1) = p1;
                let (ref s2, t2) = p2;
                if s1 == s2 {
                    result.push((s1.clone(), t1 + t2));
                    v1 = d1.next();
                    v2 = d2.next();
                } else if s1 < s2 {
                    result.push(p1.clone());
                    v1 = d1.next();
                } else {
                    result.push(p2.clone());
                    v2 = d2.next();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gives the error:

```
error: use of moved value: `v1` [E0382]
         match (v1,v2) {
                ^~
help: run `rustc --explain E0382` to see a detailed explanation
note: `v1` was previously moved here because it has type `core::option::Option<(collections::string::String, u32)>`, which is non-copyable
```

and a similar error for `v2`.  It usually shows the problem location and the previous move that causes the problem, but not here.

I've tried many permutations, and with the following change I've gotten it to compile, but I'm not happy about all the cloning and recreating tuples and recreating `Option`s.

```
match (v1, v2) {
    (None, None) => return result,
    (None, Some(x)) => {
        result.push(x.clone());
        v1 = None;
        v2 = d2.next();
    }
    (Some(x), None) => {
        result.push(x.clone());
        v1 = d1.next();
        v2 = None;
    }
    (Some(p1), Some(p2)) => {
        let (ref s1, t1) = p1;
        let (ref s2, t2) = p2;
        if s1 == s2 {
            result.push((s1.clone(), t1 + t2));
            v1 = d1.next();
            v2 = d2.next();
        } else if s1 < s2 {
            result.push(p1.clone());
            v1 = d1.next();
            v2 = Some((s2.clone(), t2));
        } else {
            result.push(p2.clone());
            v1 = Some((s1.clone(), t1));
            v2 = d2.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Adding what I'd **really** like to write, for reference, in case someone is looking for a challenge for the borrow checker:

```
fn merge(mut l1: Vec<(String, u32)>, mut l2: Vec<(String, u32)>) -> Vec<(String, u32)> {
    let mut d1 = l1.drain(..);
    let mut d2 = l2.drain(..);
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut v1 = d1.next();
    let mut v2 = d2.next();
    loop {
        match (v1, v2) {
            (None, None) => return result,
            (None, Some(p2)) => {
                result.push(p2);
                v1 = None;
                v2 = d2.next()
            }
            (Some(p1), None) => {
                result.push(p1);
                v1 = d1.next();
                v2 = None
            }
            (Some(p1 @ (s1, _)), o2 @ Some((s2, _))) if s1 < s2 => {
                result.push(p1);
                v1 = d1.next();
                v2 = o2
            }
            (o1 @ Some((s1, _)), Some(p2 @ (s2, _))) if s1 > s2 => {
                result.push(p2);
                v1 = o1;
                v2 = d2.next()
            }
            (Some((s1, t1)), Some((_, t2))) => {
                result.push((s1, t1 + t2));
                v1 = d1.next();
                v2 = d2.next()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the match on `(v1, v2)` should move the values so that each path is enforced to set `v1` and `v2`.  Still not as clean as Haskell, but closer.

Comment: Did you mean to paste two different examples of your match block? They look the same to me.

Comment: the second one assigns to both v1 and v2 on every branch, but have excessive clone operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables `v1` and `v2` move out when creating a tuple in the `match` expression. You need to modify these variables inside the `match`, so you can`t borrow them.

With `Option<T>` you can use [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) method:

```
fn merge(mut l1: Vec<(String, u32)>, mut l2: Vec<(String, u32)>) -> Vec<(String, u32)> {
    let mut d1 = l1.drain(..);
    let mut d2 = l2.drain(..);
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut v1 = d1.next();
    let mut v2 = d2.next();
    loop {
        match (v1.take(), v2.take()) {//Takes the value out of the option, leaving a None in its place.
            (None, None) => return result,
            (None, Some(x)) => {
                result.push(x);
                v2 = d2.next()
            }//v1 is None
            (Some(x), None) => {
                result.push(x);
                v1 = d1.next()
            }//v2 is None
            (Some(p1), Some(p2)) => {
                use std::cmp::Ordering::{Equal, Less, Greater};
                match p1.0.cmp(&p2.0) {
                    Equal => {
                        result.push((p1.0, p1.1 + p2.1));
                        v1 = d1.next();
                        v2 = d2.next();
                    }
                    Less => {
                        result.push(p1);
                        v1 = d1.next();
                        v2 = Some(p2);
                    }//restore v2
                    Greater => {
                        result.push(p2);
                        v1 = Some(p1); //restore v1
                        v2 = d2.next();
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have altered the code of the last branch to avoid unnecessary borrowing.

---

Disadvantage of this approach is that you may forget to assign a new value to a variable. I would recommend to return the values from the `match` expression:

```
fn merge(mut l1: Vec<(String, u32)>, mut l2: Vec<(String, u32)>) -> Vec<(String, u32)> {
    let mut d1 = l1.drain(..);
    let mut d2 = l2.drain(..);
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut v = (d1.next(), d2.next());
    loop {
        v = match (v.0.take(), v.1.take()) {
            (None, None) => return result,
            (None, Some(x)) => {
                result.push(x);
                (None, d2.next())
            }
            (Some(x), None) => {
                result.push(x);
                (d1.next(), None)
            }
            (Some(p1), Some(p2)) => {
                use std::cmp::Ordering::{Equal, Less, Greater};
                match p1.0.cmp(&p2.0) {
                    Equal => {
                        result.push((p1.0, p1.1 + p2.1));
                        (d1.next(), d2.next())
                    }
                    Less => {
                        result.push(p1);
                        (d1.next(), Some(p2))
                    }
                    Greater => {
                        result.push(p2);
                        (Some(p1), d2.next())
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Removed unnecessary `clone`s as mentioned by @mcarton

Comment: There is also no need for all those `clone`s thanks to the `drain`ed iterators.